# Angular animate on property change

Tags: angular, animation

I have a custom navigable panel for a list of items. The panel contains one databound component,  surrounded by two buttons for navigating to previous and next data. The databound component displays the currently active data. Now, I wish to show some animation when the data object changes. I am new with angular animation and finding it hard to find an example that suits my scenario. How can I trigger an animation when an @Input() property value changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not talking about router animations, I think you'll have to maintain an animation state using an `@Input()` setter and the animations `done` function. Example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmmixg

Child component ts:

```
  @Input() set data(data: any) {
    this.dataState = 'entering';
    this._data = data;
  }

  get data() { return this._data };

  _data: any;

  dataState: 'entering' | 'done' = 'done';
```

Child component html:

```
<div [@dataChange]="dataState" (@dataChange.done)="dataState = 'done'">{{ data }}</div>
```

Animation ts:

```
export const dataChange: AnimationTriggerMetadata = trigger('dataChange', [
    transition('done => entering', [
        style({
            'margin-left': '90%'
        }),
        animate('200ms ease',
            style({ 'margin-left': '*' }))
    ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question

> How can I trigger an animation when an @Input() property value
> changes?

You can have an input property in a child component as

```
Input() FadeDirection: string = "FadeFromRight";
```

and use this input property as a state to assign to the `animation trigger` as

```
[@animatecomponent]="FadeDirection"
```

and for a set of discrete states, define the transition effects as

```
transition('void => FadeFromRight', [ ... ])
```

Sample created at **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routes-animations**